# error in Predict.lm plyr Is there an alternative to mdply for prediction using newdata?

Tags: r, plyr, prediction, lm

I am at a lost in trying to figure out the logic of how to get predictions using new data passed to predict.lm using plyr in place of a loop. Can anyone help? Example:

Because I am new to r and not a highly skilled programmer, my code will be painfully inefficient.
Stackflow community:
Thanks for the suggestions to create fake code of the problem. I am hoping this will help me solve this headache.

My goal is to make predictions on a new validation dataset using the coefficients from model built on training dataset. I will eventually be building an ARIMA as well as a linear model once I can get help solving the problem.  I am building 24 regression models. One model for each hour of the day. My training data would be 90 days and my validation data would be 31 days.

## Creating Some Data

```
require(plyr)
# setting up some fake data
set.seed(31)
foo <- function(myHour, myDate){
   rlnorm(1, meanlog=0,sdlog=1)*(myHour) + (150*myDate) 
}
Hour <- 1:24
Day <-1:90
dates <-seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-3-30"), by = "day")
myData <- expand.grid( Day, Hour)
names(myData) <- c("Date","Hour")

myData$Adspend <- apply(myData, 1, function(x) foo(x[2], x[1]))
myData$Date <-dates

myData$Demand <-(rnorm(1,mean = 0, sd=1)+.75*myData$Adspend)
## ok, done with the fake data generation. 

myData

#Run regression on training data
FIT <- dlply(myData, "Hour", function(x) lm(x[,4] ~ x[,3], data=x))

# Create new fake validation dataset (31days)
Hour <- 1:24
Day <- 1:31
dates <-seq(as.Date("2012-03-31"), as.Date("2012-4-30"), by = "day")

newData <- expand.grid( Day, Hour)
names(newData) <- c("Date","Hour")
set.seed(310)

fooNew <- function(myHour, myDate){
   rlnorm(1, meanlog=0,sdlog=1)*5*(myHour) + (300*myDate) 
}

newData$AdspendNew <- apply(newData, 1, function(x) fooNew(x[2], x[1]))
newData$Date <-dates
```

I then try to make predictions of Demand using the New values for Adspend

NewDatabyHour <-dlply(newData,"Hour")

```
PREDFIT <-mdply(cbind(mod=FIT, df=NewDatabyHour), function(mod,df) {
    transform(df, pred=predict(mod,df))})
```

The error I am now getting is the following:

```
Error in data.frame(list(Date = c(15430, 15431, 15432, 15433, 15434, 15435,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 31, 90
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 31 rows but variables found have 90 rows
```

My Question is:
How do I make predictions on new data in which the new data has less observations than the training data?
My second question is: Is the process the same for auto.arima as for LM()?

Thank you again for any help.

Comment: I suggest you to look into forecast package to use forecast for `arima`: ?`forecast.Arima`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem arises in the way you are constructing your formula and then not having consistent names in the newdata argument to `predict.lm` (also `mdply` is not really what you want here)

`predict.lm` will look for objects in newdata that have the same names as the terms in your model object. Your current defintion has `x[,4]` as your 'x' term.

Instead, use the names, i.e.

```
 FIT <- dlply(myData, "Hour", function(x) lm(Demand ~ Adspend, data=x))
```

Now when you create `newData`, continue to use the name  `Adspend`

```
 newData$Adspend <- apply(newData, 1, function(x) fooNew(x[2], x[1]))
```

Now you can use `Map` (which is a wrapper for `mapply`, a base `R` function not `plyr`) to move through `FIT` and `NewDatabyHour` to do your predictions (and combine with the new data

```
predicted <-  Map(object = FIT, newdata = NewDatabyHour, 
                           f = function(object,newdata) {
                             newdata$predicted = predict(object, newdata)
                             newdata})

# combine into whole data frame again
predDF <- rbind.fill(predicted)
```

Another (entirely) different approach would be to use `nlme` `lmList`

> Data is partitioned according to the levels of the grouping factor g and individual lm fits are obtained for each data partition, using the model defined in object.

```
library(nlme)
# fit the model to each subset
FITS <- lmList(Demand ~ Adspend | Hour, data = myData)
# make the predictions
newData$predicted <- predict(FITS, newdata = newData)
```

(Please note that these regression models are almost certainly not the best way to analyse these data !)

Comment: Thank you so much mnel.  Could also recommend the right approach and I will research it. Thanks again

Comment: Oh by the way, I am going to be using a rational distributed lag in the final model, right now I am just trying to get a loop that works on a basic model.